# Providers in SSR not working - Angular 17

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering

we try to set up a basic Angular 17 project with SSR.
Background: We want to use Angular for a very slim app to provide single HTML pages.

The idea: We retrieve some settings from the URL query params.

The query params are read by the express default route. The current app.component will be rendered with the query params.
The node server looks like this:

```js
server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;
    queryParams = req.query;
    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [
          { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl },
          {
            provide: 'query-params',
            useValue: queryParams
          }
        ]
      })
      .then((html) => {
        res.send(html);
      })
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });
```

in app.component we use

```js
  constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: object,
            private http: HttpClient, private translationService: TranslateService,
              private dataService: DataService, @Optional() @Inject(new InjectionToken('query-params'))
              public queryParams: { email: string, name: string, lang: string }){
    console.log(this.queryParams);
  }
```

the query params are always null, no matter what I've tried.
I found a solution which will fetch the data from an API call, which is not working, too.

Does anybody has an idea what is wrong?
All examples I found don't use query params or based on old Angular Universal or old SSR versions.

NOTE: We don't use the ng server command, but a full ng build and node dist/server.js to run the app. So the current issue with no server.ts is not given!
Thanks

Comment: Looks like this is a known bug - not only that ng serve is not considering server.ts but that no providers are transferred to the client code at all.